# Whitelabel Error Page (type=Internal Server Error, status=500)

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, tile

I have created WebAdminDemo.war file for a spring boot project (JDK V 1.8, Tomcat V 9.0). It was run perfectly in local host. but when it deploy on server, login page is runs perfectly and after giving right credentials it redirect to the dashboard, but gives this error.

*Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/templates/admin_template.jsp'.*

SpringMVCConfiguration.java

```
package com.example.demo;


@Configuration
public class SpringMVCConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        urlBasedViewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return urlBasedViewResolver;

    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesVonfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml" });
        return tilesConfigurer;

    }
    
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/uploads/**").addResourceLocations("file:uploads/");
    }
}
```

WebAdminDemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;


@SpringBootApplication
public class WebAdminDemoApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebAdminDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebAdminDemoApplication.class); 
    }

}
```

DashboardController.java

```
package com.example.demo.controller.admin;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class DashboardController {
    @Autowired
    TypeService typeservice;
    @Autowired
    UniversityService uniservice;
    @Autowired
    StudentService studentservices;
    @Autowired
    LecturerService lecturesevices;
    @Autowired
    CourseService courseservices;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView dashboard1() {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
            List<Type> listType = typeservice.listAll();
            int unicount = uniservice.getTotUni();
            int studentcount = studentservices.getTotStudent();
            int lectcount = lecturesevices.getTotLecture();
            int coursecount = courseservices.getTotCourse();
            mv.addObject("listTypes",listType);
            mv.addObject("unicount",unicount);
            mv.addObject("studentcount",studentcount);
            mv.addObject("lectcount",lectcount);
            mv.addObject("coursecount",coursecount);
            mv.setViewName("admin.dashboard.dashboard1");
            return mv;

    }

}
```

src -> main -> webapp -> WEB-INF -> tiles

tiles.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="mytemplate"
        template="/WEB-INF/views/templates/admin_template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="content" value=""></put-attribute>
    </definition>

    <definition name="admin.dashboard.dashboard1"
        extends="mytemplate">
        <put-attribute name="content"
            value="/WEB-INF/views/admin/dashboard/dashboard1.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

admin_template.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Admin | Dashboard</title>
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
    <div class="wrapper">

        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav
            class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light">
            <!-- Left navbar links -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu"
                    href="#" role="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block"><a
                    href="index3.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block"><a href="#"
                    class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>


            <!-- Right navbar links -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <!-- Messages Dropdown Menu -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link"
                    data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> </a></li>
                <!-- Notifications Dropdown Menu -->

                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"
                    data-widget="control-sidebar" data-slide="true" href="#"
                    role="button"> <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /.navbar -->

        <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
        <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
            <!-- Brand Logo -->
            <a href="#" class="brand-link"> <img
                src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png"
                alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
                style="opacity: .8"> <span
                class="brand-text font-weight-light">Admin</span>
            </a>

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="sidebar">
                <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
                <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img
                            src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg"
                            class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <a href="#" class="d-block">Anne</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
                <nav class="mt-2">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column"
                        data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
                        <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
                        <li class="nav-item has-treeview menu-open"><a href="#"
                            class="nav-link active"> <i
                                class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                                <p>
                                    Dashboard <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                                </p>
                        </a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                                <li class="nav-item"><a
                                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"
                                    class="nav-link active"> <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                                        <p>Dashboard</p>
                                </a></li></ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </aside>

        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="content" value=""></tiles:insertAttribute>
        </div>
        <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
        <footer class="main-footer">
            <strong>Copyright &copy; 2014-2019 <a href="#">SG </a>.
            </strong>
            <div class="float-right d-none d-sm-inline-block">
                <b>Version</b> 1.0
            </div>
        </footer>

        <!-- Control Sidebar -->
        <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
            <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
        </aside>
        <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
    </div>
    <!-- ./wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
    <script>
        $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button)
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
    <script
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ChartJS -->

    <script>
        // Add the following code if you want the name of the file appear on select
        $(".custom-file-input").on(
                "change",
                function() {
                    var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
                    $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected")
                            .html(fileName);
                });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#usertable').DataTable();
        });
    </script>

    <!--    
     <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = ${listTypes};
    $( "#type" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select').selectize({
                sortField : 'text'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCFeeFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("student_id").value;
            window.location.replace("/WebAdminDemo/admin/invoice/get/" + x);
            document.getElementById("student_id").value = x;

        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getInvoiceFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("student_id").value;
            window.location.replace("/WebAdminDemo/admin/receipt/invget/" + x);
            document.getElementById("student_id").value = x;
        }

        function getInvoiceAmt() {
            var x = document.getElementById("invoice_inv_no").value;
            window.location.replace("/WebAdminDemo/admin/receipt/invtotget/" + x);
            document.getElementById("invoice_inv_no").value = x;
        }

        function getBalFee() {
            var totamt = (document.getElementById("totamt").value == "") ? 0.00
                    : parseInt(document.getElementById("totamt").value);

            var payamt = (document.getElementById("paidamount").value == "") ? 0.00
                    : parseInt(document.getElementById("paidamount").value);

            var balamt = totamt - payamt;
            document.getElementById("outstanding").value = balamt;

        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getcostFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("lecturer_id").value;
            window.location.replace("/WebAdminDemo/admin/voucher/lcostget/" + x)
        }

        function getcostdetFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("lecturercost_id").value;
            window.location.replace("/WebAdminDemo/admin/voucher/lcostdetget/" + x)
        }

        function getlcostot() {

            var hours = (document.getElementById("lhours").value == "") ? 0.00
                    : parseInt(document.getElementById("lhours").value);

            document.getElementById("outstanding").value = 0.00
        }

        function getoutstandicg() {

            var hours = (document.getElementById("lhours").value == "") ? 0.00
                    : parseInt(document.getElementById("lhours").value);
            var cost = (document.getElementById("lcost").value == "") ? 0.00
                    : parseInt(document.getElementById("lcost").value);


        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getTotFee() {
            var regfee = (document.getElementById("regfee").value == "") ? 0.00
                    : parseInt(document.getElementById("regfee").value);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getAmoduleFunction() {

            var modid = document.getElementById("courses_id").value;
            window.location.replace("/WebAdminDemo/admin/scheduler/lecture/getamodule/"
                    + modid)
        }
        
        function getEAmoduleFunction() {

            var modid = document.getElementById("courses_id").value;
            window.location.replace("/WebAdminDemo/admin/scheduler/exam/getmodule/"
                    + modid)
        }

        function getECourseFunction(){
                var intake = document.getElementById("intake_id").value;
                window.location.replace("/WebAdminDemo/admin/scheduler/exam/getcourse/"+ intake)

            }
        
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                language : 'pt-BR'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#form").on('submit', function() {

            })
        })
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide the error message for the status 500

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/templates/admin_template.jsp'.

Comment: examine the exception, I suppose

Comment: To clarify the reason why this question was closed, it's because it contains ***way*** too much code for a simple problem. You need to create a [MCVE] (emphasis on *minimal* here) that reproduces your problem. If you are still having this problem and need an answer, please use the [edit] link to update your question, following the above-linked guidance.